# JSF: navigation

Tags: java, jsf, navigation

I have to warn you: the question may be rather silly, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it right now.

I have two managed beans, let's say A and B:

```
class A
{
    private Date d8; // ...getters & setters
    public String search()
    {
        // search by d8
    }
}

class B
{
    private Date d9; //...getters & setters
    public String insert()
    {
         // insert a  new item for date d9
    }    
}
```

and then I have two JSP pages, **pageA.jsp** (the search page) and **pageB.jsp** (the input page). 
What I would like to do is placing a **commandbutton** in **pageB** so to open the search page **pageA** passing the parameter **d9** somehow, or navigating to **pageA** directly after **b.insert()**. What I would like to do is showing the search result after the insertion.

Maybe it's just that I can't see the clear, simple solution, but I'd like to know what the best practice might be here, also...

I though of these possible solutions:

1. including **A** in **B** and linking the command button with **b.a.search**
2. passing **d9** as a **hiddenInput** and adding a new method **searchFromB** in **A** (ugly!)
3. collapsing the two beans into one

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have the date (its long value) as a URL parameter? What are the scopes of these beans? Do they have any other state or purpose? That is, have you removed other variables for brevity? Are there other navigation outcomes in A other than going to B?

Comment: The scenario is (slightly) more complicated, and I'd like to avoid tangling it any further by merging the two beans or including one into another. I will consider passing parameters, as you (and some other) suggested, tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the navigation flow in faces-config.xml. In ideal scenario you would return a "status" message which would decide the flow. Read more at following link:
http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/faces-config.html
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.devtools/developer/JSF_Walkthrough8.html

As far as passing the values from one page to another is concerned you can use backing beans. More about backing beans here:
http://www.netbeans.org/kb/articles/jAstrologer-intro.html
http://www.coderanch.com/t/214065/JSF/java/backing-beans-vs-managed-beans

Hope i have understood and answered correctly to your question

**Way to share values  between beans**

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, Object.class);
return valueExp.getValue(elContext);
```

In above code "expression" would be something like `#{xyzBean.beanProperty}`
Since JSF uses singleton instances, you should be able to access the values from other beans. If you find more details on this technique, I am sure you'll get what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, I got the general idea behind JSF. This is a special case, though: I want two beans to exchange parameters, not the plain vanilla usual flow.

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect one aspect with  which you can atleast figure out attribute values between beans. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

JSF 1.1/1.2 raw doesn't provide an easy way to do this. Seam/Spring both have ways around this and there are a couple of things you can do. JSF 2 should also have solutions to this once it is released.

Probably the easiest and most expedient would be to collapse the two beans into one and make it session scoped. The worry, of course, is that this bean will not get removed and stay in session until the session times out. Yay Memory leaks!

The other solution would be to pass the date on as a GET parameter. For instance, you action method could call the

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("pageB?d9=" + convertDateToLong(d9));
```

and then get the parameter on the other side.

Comment: Well, I guess I should've planned the coding better in advance, but I will try this "passing the parameters" workaround and see if it just keeps the application working. I still don't get (and don't like) JSF... :(

Comment: JSF raw, in its current incarnation, has its share of faults. Definitely true. The Navigation model being one of the biggest ones. However, the component based concept is really good IMO and the frameworks I play with (Seam, Facelets, IceFaces and sometimes RichFaces) allow me to get around the issues with JSF. Seam, IMO, is a killer app for JSF. If you're going to do prolonged JSF development, I highly recommend you take a look at seam.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add commandButton action attribute referencing to B'insert method

> `<h:commandLink action="#{b.insert}" value="insert"/>`

2. In B'insert method,add d9 parameter as request parameter. Then return an arbitrary string from insert method.

> FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
>   fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("d9", d9);

3. Then go to faces context and add navigation from B to A with "from-outcome" as the arbitrary String you returned from insert method. But don't add redirect tag to navigation tags as it will destroy the request coming from B and the parameter you added (d9) will be cleared.

> `<from-outcome>return string of insert method</from-outcome>`
>   `<to-view-id>address of A</to-view-id>`

4. Then you might get the "d9" in A class by fetching it from request map at its constructor or in a place where its more appropriate (getters). You might add it into a session scope or place it to a hidden variable if you want to keep track of it later.

in class A, when page is navigated, A should be initialized as it will be referenced.

> FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
>   fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("d9", d9);

Sorry i cant give full code, as i have no ide at here, its internet machine at work. I could not give details therefore.

Comment: I will try this. Though I don't like the idea of working around the JSF mechanics, I think that just may be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest way is 3-rd option - have both query and insert methods in same class. And you can do something like that:

```
public String query () {
//... 
}

public String Insert() {  
 //insert
return Query(); }
```

If your classes are managed Beans you can load class **A** from class **B** and call **A.query()** in your insert method at the end. Also class **A** can have

> `<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>`

parameter in faces-config.xml and it wouldn't be instantiated again when loaded.

Comment: Session scoping the beans is fine, but just be careful about getting rid of them otherwise your memory can get eaten pretty quick for large numbers of users.